# gnome-terminal -- $SHELL fails to execute the simplest commands

Tags: bash, ubuntu, gnome-terminal

`gnome-terminal -v -- $SHELL` launches a new bash shell just as expected.

`gnome-terminal -v -- $SHELL -c 'cd /'` does nothing at all. A window briefly flashes, and that's it. Tried many other commands, like `echo` with the same result.

`journalctl -f` reveals `Failed to start VTE child process 11350 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 7182.` and that's it.

How do I debug this further?

Comment: Does it help if you launch the shell in interactive mode (-i)?

Comment: Try this `gnome-terminal -v -- $SHELL -c 'cd /; pwd; read -p "Enter a message"'`

Comment: I would expect the second one to do that; the new shell changes its working directory and exits immediately.

Comment: `-c` isn't a "do this first, then wait for the next command" option; it's a "do this and exit" option.

Answer (score 0):

this may not be the exact solution you need, but if you make a new profile for the terminal, and change the property "when command exits" to "hold terminal open"
then include the following argument:

```
gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=[new profile name here]
```

the new window will not briefly flash, and may allow more detailed debugging from whatever processes are called in the new window